# How do I redirect to error page after receiving status 404 from API call in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I have a checkin page with a params `adminId` which will call an API to check the existence of the account. Since I'm using React Router, I can put any value on the params and it will still render the page. The problem is, I don't want to render the page if the `adminId` is not verified and would like to redirect it to the homepage/404 page.

Below are the codes.

API request in CheckIn Page

```
 const { adminId } = useParams();

  const checkAccount = async () => {
    const fetchAccount = await axios
      .post(`/auth/form/${adminId}`, {
        validateStatus: () => true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 404) {
          window.location.href = "/";
          return;
        }
        console.log(res.status);
      });
  };
```

Routes.js

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <RouteRegistration path="/" component={SignIn} exact />
      <RouteRegistration path="/signup" component={CreateAccount} exact />
      <Route path="/checkin/:adminId" component={CheckIn} exact />
      <RouteProtected path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
      {/* <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact /> */}
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

const RouteRegistration = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { auth } = useContext(AuthApi);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !auth ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          // <Redirect to={`/dashboard/${adminId}`} />
          <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

const RouteProtected = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { auth } = useContext(AuthApi);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Api code

```
router.post("/form/:adminId", (req, res) => {
  const adminId = req.params.adminId;
  User.find({ adminId: adminId })
    .exec()
    .then((docs) => {
      const response = {
        usersinfo: docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            auth: true,
            message: "Account verified",
          };
        }),
      };
      if (docs.length > 0) {
        res.status(200).json(response);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "No entries found",
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Problem is not clear from your question. Is something wrong? Do you get console error? Don't your redirected or what?

most likely it problem is here `.then((res) => {` you should use `.catch((error =>` to catch errors

Comment: I only get an xhr.js error not console log error POST localhost:3000/auth/form/putinvalidadminidhere 404 (Not Found). It should redirect if the status error is equals to 404. If I tried a valid adminId, it will return console log 200.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
history.push("/")
```

OR

```
history.push("/404")
```

Also if your status code is anything other than 200, you will not receive it in response of the then callback. To catch errors, you use catch like this:

```
const fetchAccount = await axios
  .post(`/auth/form/${adminId}`, {
    validateStatus: () => true,
  })
  .then(res => history.push("/404")).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I tried adding the catch errors and still it didn't return the error. What I got is an xhr.js error POST http://localhost:3000/auth/form/putinvalidadminidhere 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using the codes below

```
const checkAccount = async () => {
    const fetchAccount = await axios
      .post(`/auth/form/${adminId}`, {
        validateStatus: () => true,
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.status);
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          window.location.href = "/";
          return;
        }
      });
  };
```